# How to get last post from a facebook group facebook scrapper

Tags: python-3.x, facebook

not work with facebook-scrapper please help me!

```
    from datetime import datetime
    from facebook_scraper import *
    import time
    import telepot
    
    
    bot = telepot.Bot('API TOKEN')
    while True:
        try:
            for post in get_posts('groups/BLABLALA/',options={"posts_per_page":1}):
                    time.sleep(10)
                    now = datetime.now()
                    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
                    if current_time==post['time']:
                        time.sleep(61)
                        bot.sendMessage(-CHAT_ID,post['text'][:100])
                    else:    
                        time.sleep(20)
                        print('empty',current_time)
        except exceptions.TemporarilyBanned:
                print("Temporarily banned, sleeping for 10m")
                time.sleep(600)
```

not work with facebook-scrapper please help me!

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them?

Comment: it works, but I have a technical problem choosing the time value